# Replacing Element name in column

Tags: r, replace

I have two dataframe 
df1

```
structure(list(d.x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3"), class = "factor"), d.Name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("d.x", 
"d.Name"), row.names = c(NA, -37L), class = "data.frame")
```

df2

```
structure(list(d.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample2", "Sample3"), class = "factor")), .Names = "d.ID", row.names =c(NA, 
-37L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to replace all the name in df2 with corresponding name of df1 file
so for examples
Sample1 will be named as A

Comment: So `df2` is a character vector, not a data.frame?

Comment: df2 is dataframe

Comment: @StuartAllen I have editted my question

Comment: Do you mean `df1$d.Name[match(df2$d.ID, df1$d.x)]`?

Comment: @Sotos Yes Exactly Same Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match()` as follows:

```
df2$d.Id.New <- df1$d.Name[match(df2$d.ID, df1$d.x)]
```

This creates a new column in `df2` which will contain the matched value from `df1`:

```
> head(df2)
     d.ID d.Id.New
1 Sample1        A
2 Sample1        A
3 Sample1        A
4 Sample1        A
5 Sample1        A
6 Sample1        A
```

Comment: Thanks @Stuart Allen